# A summation in R software

Tags: r

I need to work out the summation
(xi-m)^3

- i takes the values 1 to 25
- xi are the elements of the vector x
- m is the mean of the vector x

Is the following code correct?

```
s<-sum((xi-m)^3)
```

Comment: Probably `sum((x-mean(x))^3)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some data first:

```
set.seed(1)
x = rnorm(100, 20, 3)
```

Instead of using `x - mean(x)`, you can use `scale`, by avoiding to divide with standard deviation using `scale=F` as argument:

```
sum(scale(x[1:25], scale=F)^3)

#> sum((x[1:25]-mean(x[1:25]))^3)==sum(scale(x[1:25], scale=F)^3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I suspect that the OP may be trying to indices 1:25 of the vector x, as opposed to the summation of 1:25

Comment: If so `sum(scale(x[1:25], scale=F)^3)` or the OP wants the sum of whole vector withdrawn from the first 25 values and sum them up? It's quite unclear.

Comment: @Colonel Beauvel: nice solution! please note there is a slight but important typo in your answer, 1:25 should be x[1:25].

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is correct if the thing you are looking for is the sum of the residuals ( values minus mean) powered at 3, just consider these examples:

```
y <- rnorm(25)
> sum(y - mean(y))^3
[1] -1.710569e-49
> sum(y - mean(y)^3)
[1] -4.262774
> sum((y - mean(y))^3)
[1] 9.449698
```